# Is ill-qualified even a term?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs, adverbs, ambiguity

I know the words unqualified, disqualified. But is the term 'ill-qualified' right grammatically? In some articles I have seen that they used it to say people who are not competent enough and in some articles I have seen they have used it wrongly, but my question is it even a term in English/English vocabulary?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=ill-qualified&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cill%20-%20qualified%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cill%20-%20qualified%3B%2Cc0

Comment: 'Ill' can be used as a premodifier of a participle, meaning 'scarcely' or 'not properly/fully'. The following from  [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ill)]:  ‘He stressed that some of the goods produced locally lacked quality and were produced at a comparatively higher cost making such goods ill equipped to compete on the regional market.’ So 'He is ill qualified to ...' works; the compound adjective is perhaps _becoming_ acceptable.

Comment: There was a time when understatement was valued. Before literally was a synonym for its antonym. Then, it was not polite to say someone was not qualified, but to imply that there was room for improvement. The looser term *ill-qualified* served that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at Merriam-Webster, Oxford, and even Merriam-Webster's Unabridged Dictionary. "Ill-qualified" is not a word offered in any of these dictionaries. However, the use of a hyphen connects the two words and makes a new adjective with a combined meaning, like "just-shined Chevy" or "My I-literally-just-cleaned-him dog went in the mud again," so "ill-qualified" is actually a grammatically acceptable term and able to be used in this regard. Often, these word combinations (for example, "calculus-wise") are in large quantities, and dictionaries can not account for them all.

Comment: _Ill-qualified_ may not be in the dictionaries now, but the link provided by Hot Licks shows that it was more commonly used in the past. There are plenty of other compound words beginning with _ill_ (meaning _badly_, not _sick_) such as ill-concealed, ill-judged, ill-fated...

Comment: Are you suggesting "funnier" is not a word? (Also, "it is not a word, but it is a word"? I know what you mean, but still...) What is an "official word"?

Comment: Thank you both. I made corrections.